# Spotify check if access_token is expired

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

A small questions. At the moment i'm using Spotify Webapi, and I want to know is there a Web API Endpoint to check if an access_token is expired? At the moment I'm using

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
```

to check if an access_token is expired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no endpoint to check how long time there's left until a token expires, but you can use the response to the access token request to find out.

As explained in the [Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/), the response including the access token also contains

```
expires_in   int    The time period (in seconds) for which the access token is valid.
```